# Differentiate between a WorldPay future payment and initial payment

Tags: php, recurring-billing, worldpay

I have read the WorldPay FuturePay documentation and I am clear on everything and what to do. I have a few questions that keep lurring around my head and causing confusion. If someone senior or with experience on this shine some light it would be very thankful of you.

I have setup a recurring payment with an initial amount of £x to be taken when setting up the payments. My questions are:

- What variable do I have to check from the callback response that notifies the initial payment has been made that has just been setup? Meaning the first time the consumer redirects to WorldPay site to make the first ever payment not the future payments.
- What variable do I have to check from the callback response that determines this is a future payment?
- Any custom variables that will be defined during the first initial payment would these be available in the callback response for future payments? Basically, would these be included every month automatically?

Thank you for taking the timeout reading this.

Comment: Did you get your answer? I am struggling with same.